# How to copy a photo from gallery to dataDirectory?

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I'm trying to copy a file from photo gallery to dataDirectory on Android 5.0 device. 
Unfortunely Cordova camera plugin returns path in format like: content://media/external/images/media/8793

```js
 var options = {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };

            return $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (result) {
                return handlePictureResult(result);
            })
```

$cordovaFile.copyFile('content://media/external/images/media/8793', null, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName) simply doesn't work.

Any ideas how can I copy file from gallery (path with content://) to cordova.file.dataDirectory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you should handle it (with [fileTransfer plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) instead of [file one](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/)) :

```
app.controller(
    'MainController',
    [
        '$scope', '$cordovaCamera', '$cordovaFileTransfer',
        function($scope, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFileTransfer)
        {
            $scope.images = { imageUri: '' };

            $scope.getImage = function()
            {
                var options = {
                    quality: 50,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                };

                $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(
                    function(fileUri)
                    {
                        console.log(fileUri);

                        $cordovaFileTransfer.download(fileUri, cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'my-image.jpg', {}, true).then(
                            function(fileEntry)
                            {
                                $scope.images.imageUri = fileEntry.nativeURL;
                            },
                            function (error)
                            {
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    function(error)
                    {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

And the HTML (just in case) :

```
<section ng-controller="MainController">
    <img ng-src="{{ images.imageUri }}">
    <button ng-click="getImage()">GET IMAGE</button>
</section>
```

Comment: How come you are using FileTransfer and not File? Is there a bug with File? Is using FileTransfer in such a case recommended in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: To me this return this "Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%25253A74 from pid=826, uid=10104 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()"
I have this android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS in my manifest xml

Answer (score 0):

You can received the image data on base64 and save it yourself.

I did a library for easy manage of FileAPI on cordova/HTML5, maybe is usefull for you: https://github.com/exos/cofs

```
var fs = new CoFS();

var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
};

return $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (data) {
    fs.writeFile(
        cordova.file.dataDirectory + '/example.jpg',
        data,
        'base64',
        function (err) {
            // if not err, success!
        }
    );
});
```